# Sections on my WordPress website redirect to another subdomains and I can´t stop it from redirecting

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I don´t even know if this problem is able to be solved by using code. So on my website called mpufastlane.com I have a section called "Vorteile auf einen Blick" and when you click on the text or block it redirects you to another page. I can´t change this because it´s somehow hardcoded by the theme provider and I can´t change it. It would mean the world to me if someone has an idea for my problem or tell me where I have to search to find a solution. I never used the theme on this website called Consultio and my boss bought it and told me to work with it.

Comment: If it was a theme that was purchased, I would check with the theme creator. Purchased/Premium themes typically have their own support systems.
https://themeforest.net/item/consultio-consulting-business-wordpress/25376496/support

Comment: Because it's a theme that's not free, the majority of people won't have access to the code/settings of the theme, so you'll have a rather difficult time finding support here on Stack Overflow for it unless you luck out and someone familiar with this specific theme sees your post.